# Recursive Quicksort: Why this partition is wrong?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm coding a recursive 3-way partitioning in C++, but I don't see what's wrong here. (It is 97% of the time correct, **sometimes** incorrect. That's making me hard to debug.)

Expected invariant: After the partitioning, `A[p, ..., p + less1 + less2 - 1]` is less than pivot, `A[p + less1 + less2, ..., p + less1 + less2 + same1 + same2 - 1]` is the same with pivot, the rest is bigger than pivot.

Wrong result: "The middle" part (the part with values the same with pivot) doesn't locate correctly.

Reproducable test case:
`A = {0, 1, 4, 7, 6, 9, 3, 10, 11, 12, 2, 8, 5}`
`p = 0, r = 12, pivot = 11`

Expected output of `less` : 11

Current output : 10

Code:

```
template <typename T>
void PPartition(std::vector<T>& A, size_t p, size_t r, const T& pivot, std::size_t& less, std::size_t& same) {
    if (p == r) {
        less = A[p] < pivot;
        same = A[p] == pivot;
        return;
    }
    std::size_t m = (p + r) / 2;
    std::size_t less1 = 0, less2 = 0, same1 = 0, same2 = 0;
    PPartition(A, p, m, pivot, less1, same1);
    PPartition(A, m + 1, r, pivot, less2, same2);
    if (less2 > m - p + 1 - less1) {
        // sends "less" part of the right to the left
        for (std::size_t k = 0; k < m - p + 1 - less1; k++) {
            std::swap(A[p + less1 + k], A[m + less2 - k]);
        }
        // maintains "equal" part
        for (std::size_t k = 0; k < same1 + same2; k++) {
            std::swap(A[p + less1 + less2 + k], A[m + less2 + same2 - k]);
        }
    } else {
        // sends "less" part of the right to the left
        for (std::size_t k = 0; k < less2; k++) {
            std::swap(A[p + less1 + k], A[m + less2 - k]);
        }
        // maintains "equal" part
        for (std::size_t k = 0; k < same1 + same2; k++) {
            std::swap(A[p + less1 + less2 + k], A[m + less2 + same2 - k]);
        }
    }
    less = less1 + less2;
    same = same1 + same2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Self-answer:

If `less2 == 0`, then We shouldn't swap "middle" partition of the left part with the right part.

```
template <typename T>
void PPartition(std::vector<T>& A, size_t p, size_t r, const T& pivot, std::size_t& less, std::size_t& same) {
    if (p == r) {
        less = A[p] < pivot;
        same = A[p] == pivot;
        return;
    }
    std::size_t m = (p + r) / 2;
    std::size_t less1 = 0, less2 = 0, same1 = 0, same2 = 0;
    PPartition(A, p, m, pivot, less1, same1);
    PPartition(A, m + 1, r, pivot, less2, same2);
    if (less2 > m - p + 1 - less1) {
        for (std::size_t k = 0; k < m - p + 1 - less1; k++) {
            std::swap(A[p + less1 + k], A[m + less2 - k]);
        }
        for (std::size_t k = 0; k < same1 + same2 && p + less1 + k < m + same2 - k; k++) {
            std::swap(A[p + less1 + less2 + k], A[m + less2 + same2 - k]);
        }
    } else {
        for (std::size_t k = 0; k < less2; k++) {
            std::swap(A[p + less1 + k], A[m + less2 - k]);
        }
        if (less2 > 0) {
            for (std::size_t k = 0; k < same1 + same2; k++) {
                std::swap(A[p + less1 + less2 + k], A[m + less2 + same2 - k]);
            }
        } else {
            for (std::size_t k = 0; k < same2; k++) {
                std::swap(A[p + less1 + same1 + k], A[m + same2 - k]);
            }
        }
    }
    less = less1 + less2;
    same = same1 + same2;
}
```